# ContentEditable div focus. cursor goes little up in EDGE and IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

In my React component, I have written below code in render function of a pop up.
When the popup comes up, **ref.focus()** gets executed,and focus comes on the div, ***but cursor blinks little up***. 
This is happening **on** **EDGE and IE** only, but working fine on chrome and firefox.
Note: If clicking on the div then cursor comes at right position in EDGE and IE also.[ I mean the cursor comes at wrong position for the first time only, once I click on the div cursor comes at right position.]

```
 render() {
    <Row>
     <Col sm={2} className="resendContentCol">
        <div contentEditable="true" ref={(ref) => {{ref.focus();};}}>
             {partnerInv.onboardFirstName}
        </div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
    }
```

In CSS:

```
.resendContentCol [contentEditable="true"]{
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-height: 28px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.resendContentCol [contentEditable="true"]:active,
.resendContentCol [contentEditable="true"]:focus{
  border: 1px solid #99bbe8;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

On Edge:
[image: On Edge]

On IE:
[image: On IE]